# Prevent Spring Boot Invoking EC2MetadataUtils.getItems on startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having an issue where EC2MetaDataUtils.getItems is being invoked on application start up ( Spring boot app), we do not use EC2 and so the calls made to AWS to get Metadata always fail, the application attempts to get this data 3 times and so this is adding around 15 seconds to the start time of the application.

I have been searching high and low for solutions I found a promising solution would suggested the following `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { ContextResourceLoaderAutoConfiguration.class, ContextResourceLoaderConfiguration.class, ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration.class })`

However when I try to start up the application it complains that ContextResourceLoaderConfiguration.class cannot be excluded as it is not auto configuration; if I just exclude the other 2 the application still invokes the MetaDataUtils.

Has anyone experienced this in the past and managed to resolve it?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved with the following:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration.class, ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class, ContextResourceLoaderAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: I don't think that looks cleaner approach when it deploys on AWS cloud.

Answer (score 1):

when running spring-boot-application with AWS dependencies  ,
It invokes stack auto-configuration , you need to disable it ,

add following to application.yml

```
cloud.aws.stack.auto: false
```

Answer (score 0):

SpringBoot application should not do any call to EC2. This mean your are using some AWS specific library/component/what ever and this library on startup do this call.

Please check your dependencies and context configuration. There are nothing about SpringBoot. There is something with your custom dependencies/components.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using EC2, you can try removing the `spring-cloud-aws*` libraries from your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring profiles to differentiate between cloud and default profiles. For cloud profile, you can use `spring-cloud-aws` artifact to get metadata about EC2 instance which you need EC2 read permission access from an attached IAM role whereas for default profile, you don't need to worry about cloud environment and disable the cloud configuration properties which should not cause an issue for the application startup.